# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I've looked through some other question of the same type and trying to find the answer but I wasn't able to see what is wrong, if someone could point it out for me would be great!

So basically I'm creating a "Memory Game" in which I have to set up a default background image to each card, but this image has to change each time I run it again. Also I gotta create and array list with the foreground images (which are 21) but I'll only use 8 per game. They also have to change each time I run the program. That said, what I got so far is:

```
public class GameBoard extends javax.swing.JPanel implements Runnable {

    private JLabel[] _Labels = new JLabel[8];
    private Card[] _Cards = new Card[16];

    public GameBoard(){

        setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));

        for(int i = 0; i<8; i=i+1){

            _Labels[i] = new JLabel();

        }

        for(int i = 0; i<16; i=i+2){

            _Cards[i] = new Card(_Labels[i]);
            _Cards[i+1] = new Card(_Labels[i]);

            add(_Cards[i].getLabel());
            add(_Cards[i+1].getLabel());

            _Labels[i].addMouseListener(new LabelListener(_Cards[i]));
            _Labels[i+1].addMouseListener(new LabelListener(_Cards[i+1]));

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {


    }

}
```

The card class is:

```
public class Card{

    private JLabel _Label;

    ImageIcon imageOne;

    ImageIcon imageTwo;

    public Card(JLabel once){

        _Label = once;

 //-----------------------Foreground--------------------------------

        ArrayList<String> foregroundCard = new ArrayList<String>();       
        int i = 1;
        while(i < 23){
            if(i > 9){
                String addGreaterNine = "F" + i + ".png";
                foregroundCard.add(addGreaterNine);
            }
            else{
                String addLesserNine = "F0" + i +".png";
                foregroundCard.add(addLesserNine);
            }
            i = i + 1;
        }

        //-----------------Add 8---------------------

        int a = 0;

        while(a < 8){

            Collections.shuffle(foregroundCard); 

            ArrayList<String> stringsGoingToBeUsed = new ArrayList<String>();            
            stringsGoingToBeUsed.add(foregroundCard.get(0));
            stringsGoingToBeUsed.add(foregroundCard.get(0));

            for(int l = 0; l<16; l=l+1){

            Collections.shuffle(stringsGoingToBeUsed);  

            String frontName = "Images/" + stringsGoingToBeUsed.get(0);
            imageOne = new ImageIcon(frontName);

            }

            a = a + 1;

        }       


//------------------------Background--------------------------------        

        ArrayList<String> backgroundCard = new ArrayList<String>();
        backgroundCard.add("B01.png");
        backgroundCard.add("B02.png");
        backgroundCard.add("B03.png");
        Collections.shuffle(backgroundCard);
        String location = "Images/" + backgroundCard.get(0);
        imageTwo = new ImageIcon(location);

//-------------------------------------------------------------------        

        _Label.setIcon(imageTwo);   

    }
    public void TurnCard (){

        ImageIcon temp;
        temp = imageTwo;
        imageTwo = imageOne;
        imageOne = temp;
        _Label.setIcon(imageTwo);

    }

    public JLabel getLabel(){

        return _Label;

    }

}
```

And the LabelListener class is:

```
public class LabelListener implements MouseListener {

    private Card _Card;

    public LabelListener(Card c){

        _Card = c;

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

        _Card.TurnCard();

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

The main method is:

```
public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame main = new JFrame("Memory Game");
        main.add(new GameBoard());  

        main.pack();
        main.setVisible(true);
        main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for not including the exception trace (which includes the line numbers and which points you right at the error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's because `_Labels` is an array with 8 elements, however you're attempting to reference up to 16 in the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i<16; i=i+2){
    ...
    _Labels[i+1].addMouseListener(new LabelListener(_Cards[i+1]));
    ...
```

Comment: Note that this is a runtime error, not a compile error (i.e., Java will still compile the code but the error only occurs once it's run). Also, the stack trace produced should give you the line number of the error, which will help you track it down.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i<16; i=i+2){

        _Cards[i] = new Card(_Labels[i]);
        _Cards[i+1] = new Card(_Labels[i]);

        add(_Cards[i].getLabel());
        add(_Cards[i+1].getLabel());

        _Labels[i].addMouseListener(new LabelListener(_Cards[i]));
        _Labels[i+1].addMouseListener(new LabelListener(_Cards[i+1]));

    }
```

Doesnt work as _Labels is only size 8 a possible solution would be to split this into separate loops or change the program architecture.

Answer (score 0):

As there is a mismatch between the number of `Card` and `JLabel` array items which produces the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You could add another index `j` to account for this:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 16; i += 2, j++) {

   _Cards[i] = new Card(_Labels[j]); // AIOOBE was happening here
   _Cards[i + 1] = new Card(_Labels[j]);

   add(_Cards[i].getLabel());
   add(_Cards[i + 1].getLabel());

   _Labels[j].addMouseListener(new LabelListener(_Cards[i]));

   // not necessary
   // _Labels[j + 1].addMouseListener(new LabelListener(_Cards[i + 1])); 
}
```

Aside: Use Java naming conventions for naming variables, such as `cards` in place of `_Cards`.